# Vertically align three divs with image on right

Tags: html, css

I want to have 3 divs with text vertically aligned top, middle and bottom of the parent with an image on the right.

If possible, I need to support older browsers as well. Sorry if this is simple, I have very little experience with css.

Comment: try `flex` it will save you a day.

Comment: Post the code in the snippet please

Comment: It will be really great if you can share a picture which described your design!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  height: fit-content;
  display:flex;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.textPart{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.text{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}

.imgPart {
  background-image: url('https://www.placehold.it/200x400');
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="textPart">
   <div class="text"><h1>Some text here</h1></div>
   <div class="text"><h1>Some text here</h1></div>
   <div class="text"><h1>Some text here</h1></div>
 </div>
 <div class="imgPart"></div>
 </div>
```

The key point here is `display: flex`.

And about the browser support, most of the browsers, including may old versions, also support flexbox with or without the prefix `-webkit-`. (src- caniuse.com)

Answer (score 0):

> I used "float" property for this problem. because it is simple and have a good browser support. but you must notice that the width of two column is variable according to image size. you could use any image you want in "img" tag.

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#whole-parent {
    background-color: rgb(120,110,122);
    color: #fff;
}

/* these two class is directly related to layout */
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table; 
}

.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
/* ------------- */

.wid1 {
    width: 70%;
}

.wid2 {
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>three divs</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
   <section id="whole-parent" class="clearfix">
       <div class="column wid1">
           <div>
           <h1>div1</h1>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum enim, nulla rerum. Minima tenetur dignissimos ab nulla rem. Eaque est exercitationem illum quod non rem nam nostrum corporis! Amet, alias deserunt itaque culpa provident ullam nihil atque. Illum minima reiciendis, mollitia repellendus assumenda libero, ducimus. Vel, a, incidunt. Optio laudantium, facere possimus laboriosam fuga accusamus.
           </div>
           
           <div>
           <h1>div2</h1>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum enim, nulla rerum. Minima tenetur dignissimos ab nulla rem. Eaque est exercitationem illum quod non rem nam nostrum corporis! Amet, alias deserunt itaque culpa provident ullam nihil atque. Illum minima reiciendis, mollitia repellendus assumenda libero, ducimus. Vel, a, incidunt. Optio laudantium, facere possimus laboriosam fuga accusamus.
           </div>
           
           <div>
           <h1>div3</h1>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum enim, nulla rerum. Minima tenetur dignissimos ab nulla rem. Eaque est exercitationem illum quod non rem nam nostrum corporis! Amet, alias deserunt itaque culpa provident ullam nihil atque. Illum minima reiciendis, mollitia repellendus assumenda libero, ducimus. Vel, a, incidunt. Optio laudantium, facere possimus laboriosam fuga accusamus.
           </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="column wid2">
       <img src="book1.jpg" alt="an image">
       </div>
   </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```